# Solidity compiler is giving error ( Expected token Semicolon got 'RBrace' )

Tags: contract-deployment, remix

I am compiling a contract from [browser-solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.2+commit.af6afb04.js),but I am getting `Error: Expected token Semicolon got 'RBrace'` . The part of contract that throws error is:

```
contract owned {
address public owner;

function owned() {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

modifier onlyOwner {
    if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
    _
} }
```

The surprising thing is same contract is deployed from Mist without any issue. So why browser solidity is throwing error.Is there a bug in solidity-compiler or something is not right with my contract?

Comment: It is good practice to capitalise your contract names: `Owned`, not `owned`.

Comment: I was following [Create a crpytopcurrency](https://www.ethereum.org/token#full-coin-code), here contract name begin with lowercase, I followed same practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You now need to add a semicolon after `_`, so your code should read `_;`.

From [Solidity - Version 0.4.0](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.0):

> Minimal changes to be made for upgrade:
>
> - Add payable to all functions that want to receive Ether (including the constructor and the fallback function).
> - **Change `_` to `_;` in modifiers.**
> - Add version pragma to each file: pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
>
> Breaking Changes:
>
> - Source files have to specify the compiler version they are compatible with using e.g. pragma solidity ^0.4.0; or pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.4.8;
> - Functions that want to receive Ether have to specify the new payable modifier (otherwise they throw).
> - Contracts that want to receive Ether with a plain "send" have to implement a fallback function with the payable modifier. Contracts now throw if no payable fallback function is defined and no function matches the signature.
> - Failing contract creation through "new" throws.
> - Division / modulus by zero throws.
> - Function call throws if target contract does not have code
> - Modifiers are required to contain `_` (use if (false) `_` as a workaround if needed).
> - Modifiers: return does not skip part in modifier after _.
> - **Placeholder statement `_` in modifier now requires explicit `;`.**
> - ecrecover now returns zero if the input is malformed (it previously returned garbage).
> - The constant keyword cannot be used for constructors or the fallback function.
> - Removed --interface (Solidity interface) output option
> - JSON AST: General cleanup, renamed many nodes to match their C++ names.
> - JSON output: srcmap-runtime renamed to srcmapRuntime.
> - Moved (and reworked) standard library contracts from inside the compiler to github.com/ethereum/solidity/std (import "std"; or import owned; do not work anymore).
> - Confusing and undocumented keyword after was removed.
> - New reserved words: abstract, hex, interface, payable, pure, static, view.